# I cannot install torch with pip3 but I can with pip

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

So following the guide on pytorchs homepage I should be able to install pytorch by running:

```
pip3 install torch===1.3.1 torchvision===0.4.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

If I do so, I get the error message

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch===1.3.1 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
No matching distribution found for torch===1.3.1
```

If I install using pip (and not pip3) it works, but I cannot import torch afterwards - it seems like pip3 is handling my packages.

OS: `Windows 10`

IDE: `VScode`

Comment: if you omit `-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`, what's the result? (i.e. just run `pip3 install torch===1.3.1 torchvision===0.4.2`)

Comment: Same error call

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that I was using a 32-bit version (eventhough python told me it was a 64 bit). Installing the 64-bit solved the issue